# How to use mysql's "use index()" clause in hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria-api

I am using criteria API in my project but the query which is created from hibernate is very slow.

When I run the explain on the query I found that the required index is not being used. So I tried to use `"use index()"` clause provided by `MYSQL` and the query took only 5 sec. which was taking 70 sec.

But the issue is I am using criteria API and wanted to know that is there any option to use `"use index()"` clause in criteria API

Answer (score 0):

Although [this solution](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/10/07/using-use-index-with-hibernatemysql/) was tested with HQL, it may work with Criteria API too.

You basically define a new Hibernate function, so for this HQL:

> ```
> select table 
> from MyTable table 
> where useindex(table, my_index) is true and table.feature is not null
> ```

You'd get this SQL:

> ```
> select table 
> from MyTable table 
> where useindex(table, my_index) is true and table.feature is not null
> ```